# The file <myproject>.xcodeproj doesn't exist

Tags: xcode, project

I have a folder with my working xcode project in it. However when I go to copy and paste the entire folder to a different location and then go to open the .xcodeproj file inside, I get an error saying the project doesn't exist!

Does anyone know why it's doing this and how I can open the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced the same problem with an iOS project I checked out from a repository. The .xcodeproj file is a package that contains several files. You can view the contents by right-clicking on your .xcodeproj file and selecting "Show Package Contents". Inside the package, it's my understanding that you'll need several types of files to be present.

`project.pbxproj` contains all the references to files in your project, as well as many of the project settings. If your .xcodeproj package doesn't contain this, you're up a creek without a paddle.

When I first checked out my project, only this file was present and I was experiencing the same problem. I then copied and pasted two files, `[login].pbxuser` and `[login].mode1v3`, from the .xcodeproj file of another project. These files didn't appear to contain any settings specific to this project, and it helped get my project up and running. I know I'm a little late to answer your question, but I found it while searching for an answer myself.